# I need help solving the equation for my revision class

Tags: analytic-geometry

I need to solve the radius and the center point.
$$
x^2+y^2=6x-2y-8
$$
Under this is my attempt of solving it
$$
x^2-6x+y^2+2y=-8
$$
$$
x^2-6x+9+y^2\ +2x+1=-8+1+9
$$
$$
\left(x+3\right)^2+\left(y-1\right)^2=2^2
$$
On 2nd I added the integers to both sides

Comment: The last formula has more than 2 errors

Comment: Expand your last line out.

Comment: The 2nd to last line also has an error.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

By solving you can get
$$x^2+y^2=6x−2y−8$$

$$(x^2-6x+9-9) + (y^2+2y+1-1) =-8$$

$$(x-3)^2 +(y+1)^2 = 2.$$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Close but no cigars :-)

At the right side you have $=2$, which does not equal $=2^2$ but $=(\sqrt{2})^2$

:-)

Comment: And two other errors on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+y^2=6x-2y-8$

$\Rightarrow x^2-6x+y^2+2y=-8$

$\Rightarrow x^2-6x+9+y^2+2y+1=-8+1+9$

(You have written wrongly $2x$ instead of $2y$)

$\Rightarrow (x^2-6x+9)+(y^2+2y+1)=2$

$\Rightarrow \left(x-3\right)^2+\left(y+1\right)^2={(\sqrt2)}^2$

(You have done wrong calculation here)

> We know that,the equation of a circle with center at $(a,b)$ and with radius $r$ is, ${(x-a)}^2+ {(y-b)}^2= r^2$.

So comparing with above equation we get that, the center is $(3,-1)$ and radius is $\sqrt 2$.